# Selecting top ten rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table gainfinal consists of three columns-countrycode, year and values. I want to select ten rows with top ten values. First, I created a rank according to values with the following Query.

```
    SELECT countrycode, `values`,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM gainfinal CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
    WHERE year = 2000
    ORDER By `values` DESC ;
```

Now, I need to select the top ten rows with the highest rank. How can I do it ?

Comment: add `limit 10` to your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT countrycode, `values`,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM gainfinal CROSS JOIN
(SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
WHERE year = 2000
ORDER By `values` DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
LIMIT
```

in SQL so example:

```
SELECT countrycode, `values`,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM gainfinal CROSS JOIN
(SELECT @curRank := 0) vars
WHERE year = 2000
ORDER By `values` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get 10 rows starting from row 20 using:Limit

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20 --Equivalent to LIMIT 20, 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use your rank variable in where statement

```
...WHERE year = 2000 and @curRank <11;
```